# How to listen to a random tcp socket in node.js

Tags: networking, node.js, tcp, port, listen

I know I can create a tcp server like that in node.js

```
var dataServer = net.createServer(function (stream) { 
}); 

dataServer.on("listening", function() { 
    // this data server listen to a random port 
    // but how can I get the number of port 
    console.log(dataServer.localPort) 
} 

dataServer.listen(0, '0.0.0.0');
```

But I don't know how to get the port number and send to another service.

Or I should find a random available port and pass to dataServer.listen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the address and port the server is listening on using the `address` method.

```
dataServer.address();
// => { address: '0.0.0.0', port: 49717 }
```

Comment: Do you know the ans for this too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520475/how-can-a-node-js-socket-
server-know-which-ip-or-domain-that-the-client-connect-t

Thanks

Comment: Will that auto assignment get me a port that is not used currently? And how can I limit the random assignment, like between a range of numbers?